# Не отображается модальное окно на вкладках jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

На странице организованы вкладки через:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

На каждой вкладке открывается видео с ютуба в модальном окне.

```
<a href="#" onclick="open_popup('#box-2', 640, 360, 'ZoMo59c8mQ4')">
<img src="//img.youtube.com/vi/ZoMo59c8mQ4/mqdefault.jpg" width="310" height="180" >
</a>
```

скрипт:

```
function open_popup(box, width, height, yt) {
  if(!$(box+' iframe').length && yt) {
   $(box).append('<iframe id="yt" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'+yt+'?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
 }
 $(box+' .popup-close').html('<div class="popup-l1"></div><div class="popup-l2"></div>');
  if(width) $(box).css({'width': width, 'margin-left': -(width/2)});
 if(height) $(box).css({'height': height, 'margin-top': -(height/2)});
  else $(box).css('margin-top', -($(box).height()/2));
  $(box).show();
```

На первой вкладке всё работает прекрасно, но начиная со второй и далее на всех вкладках модальное окно не открывается.
Если после запуска видео вернуться на первую вкладку,то там есть модальное окно. И оно корректно работает. z-index: 9. 
Почему модальное окно не отображается на последующих вкладках? Куда копать?

Comment: Данная реализация модального окна не имеет подложки, по этому страница прыгает и отображается только там, где есть:
`<div id="box-2" class="pop-up"></div>` а поскольку ближайший div находится на первой странице, то и окно отображается там же.
Для решения данной проблемы пришлось использовать другую реализацию модального окна. Код не привожу из-за громоздкости.

Comment: Если кто-то решится использовать сей чудный вариант, то можно div просто вынести за пределы tabs ов. Мне этот вариант не подошёл из-за специфики задачи.